# Deactivating Ui-router's ui-sref-active on root state on a nested configuration

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have 2 buttons and both have ui-sref-active.

```
<a class="button" ui-sref-active="button-selected" ui-sref="main">
    <p>View patients</p>
</a>
<a class="button" ui-sref-active="button-selected" ui-sref="main.create">
    <p>Add patients</>
</a>
```

and css

```
.button-selected {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

I'm wondering why when I click the 2nd button with the state "main.create", the class "button-selected" isn't removed from the first one. So the color #0000FF is still seen on the first button. Looks like "main" state is always active. Is it because it's the root state? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is been added to both states because you should use [`ui-sref-active-eq`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active-eq) instead of `ui-sref-active`.

```
<a class="button" ui-sref-active-eq="button-selected" ui-sref="main">
    <p>View patients</p>
</a>
<a class="button" ui-sref-active-eq="button-selected" ui-sref="main.create">
    <p>Add patients</>
</a>
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much! Why are the Angular docs I found are using ui-sref-active instead of ui-sref-active-eq?

Comment: You are using [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)
 right? Probably because the normal case is that you are using ui-sref-active to stylish navigation between the principal states and not states parents and his children. W